# push the contents of array into another array without looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Here's a simple piece of JavaScript where I want to add the contents of `orders.foo` and `orders2.foo` to a single-dimensional `ordersArr`.

```
let _ = require('underscore');

let ordersArr = [];
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

ordersArr = _.map(orders.foo, order => order)

orders2 = {
        foo: [
                {x: 2, b: 3},
                {y: 5, c: 4},
                {a: 3, d: 6}
        ]
}


let tOrders = _.map(orders2.foo, order => order);
ordersArr.push(tOrders)

console.log(ordersArr);
```

The problem with this code is that `push` in this case creates a multi-dimensional array:

**Output**

```
[
  { x: 1, b: 2 },
  { y: 1, c: 3 },
  { a: 2, d: 4 },
  [ { x: 2, b: 3 }, { y: 5, c: 4 }, { a: 3, d: 6 } ]
]
```

How do I iterate the contents of `orders.foo` and `orders2.foo` and have their results as one single dimension array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `spread` the content of both arrays into the new array

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [4,5,6];
const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2];
console.log(arr3);
// prints [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Spreading `arr2` into `arr1` also works.

```
arr1.push(...arr2);
console.log(arr1);
// prints [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So changing

```
ordersArr.push(tOrders)
```

to

```
ordersArr.push(...tOrders);
```

should work.

For a full answer:

```
let ordersArr = [];
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

orders2 = {
        foo: [
                {x: 2, b: 3},
                {y: 5, c: 4},
                {a: 3, d: 6}
        ]
}

ordersArr.push(...orders.foo, ...orders2.foo);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using underscore [`_.flatten`](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten):

```js
const 
  orders = { foo: [ {x: 1, b: 2}, {y: 1, c: 3}, {a: 2, d: 4} ] },
  orders2 = { foo: [ {x: 2, b: 3}, {y: 5, c: 4}, {a: 3, d: 6} ] };
  
const ordersArr = _.flatten([orders.foo, orders2.foo]);

console.log(ordersArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Using javascript [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const 
  orders = { foo: [ {x: 1, b: 2}, {y: 1, c: 3}, {a: 2, d: 4} ] },
  orders2 = { foo: [ {x: 2, b: 3}, {y: 5, c: 4}, {a: 3, d: 6} ] };
  
const ordersArr = [...orders.foo, ...orders2.foo];

console.log(ordersArr);
```

Using javascript [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const 
  orders = { foo: [ {x: 1, b: 2}, {y: 1, c: 3}, {a: 2, d: 4} ] },
  orders2 = { foo: [ {x: 2, b: 3}, {y: 5, c: 4}, {a: 3, d: 6} ] };
  
const ordersArr = orders.foo.concat(orders2.foo);

console.log(ordersArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

The spread operator mentioned above is the best 2021 way to do it.

```
let ordersArr = [...orders.foo, ...orders2.foo];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.concat()](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/concat)

```js
let orders1 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
};

let orders2 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 2, b: 3},
        {y: 5, c: 4},
        {a: 3, d: 6}
    ]
};

console.log( orders1.foo.concat(orders2.foo) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge the arrays and create a single new array:

```
let tOrders = orders.foo.concat(orders2.foo);
```

```js
let ordersArr = [];
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

ordersArr = _.map(orders.foo, order => order)

orders2 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 2, b: 3},
        {y: 5, c: 4},
        {a: 3, d: 6}
    ]
}

let tOrders = orders.foo.concat(orders2.foo);
console.log(tOrders)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Another option using [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let ordersArr = [];
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

orders2 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 2, b: 3},
        {y: 5, c: 4},
        {a: 3, d: 6}
    ]
}

let tOrders = [orders.foo, orders2.foo].flat();
console.log(tOrders)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Immutable merge of arrays**

Creates a new array.

1. Merge using the spread operator

```js
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

let orders2 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 2, b: 3},
        {y: 5, c: 4},
        {a: 3, d: 6}
     ]
}

const mergeResult = [...orders.foo, ...orders2.foo];
console.log(mergeResult);
```

2. Merge using `array.concat()` method

```js
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

let orders2 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 2, b: 3},
        {y: 5, c: 4},
        {a: 3, d: 6}
     ]
}

const mergeResult = orders.foo.concat(orders2.foo);
console.log(mergeResult);
```

**Mutable merge of arrays**

Merge it into existing array.

1. Merge using `array.push()` method

```js
let orders = {
    foo: [
        {x: 1, b: 2},
        {y: 1, c: 3},
        {a: 2, d: 4}
    ]
}

let orders2 = {
    foo: [
        {x: 2, b: 3},
        {y: 5, c: 4},
        {a: 3, d: 6}
     ]
}

orders.foo.push(...orders2.foo);
console.log(orders.foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add one more flavor to the list. You can create a shallow copy of an array using the built-in `slice` method, which has been with us for a very long time:

```js
var ordersArr = orders.foo.slice();
```

Now you can add the contents of the other array using `push` and `apply`:

```js
ordersArr.push.apply(ordersArr, orders2.foo);
```

Et voilá, `ordersArr` is now a one-dimensional array containing all elements of both `orders.foo` and `orders2.foo`. Works even in ES3!

For inspiration, you can find lots of nice little tricks like this in [the Underscore source code](https://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore-esm.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for you.

```
let tOrders = _.map(orders2.foo, order => order);
tOrders.foreach((element)=>{
ordersArr.push(element)
})
console.log(ordersArr);
```

Comment: The post title says without looping, but this answer will work